# ng-click not working inside of ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have a site that links to a component through ng-include:

```
<div id="tracklist">
  <ng-include src="'partials/tracks.html'">
  </ng-include>
</div>
```

the partial looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TracklistController">
  <div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
    <a ng-click="$('body').css('background-color', 'red')" href="#/tracks/{{ track.id  }}" class="track-link" data-audio-source="{{ track.source }}">{{ track.trackNumber + " - " + track.title  }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It renders fine and works, but my ng-click event does not fire for some reason. Note that changing the body background color is just an obvious test to see if it's failing. I've tried it with my actual function (declared globally when the document loads for now), and I've also tested with console.log. None of it works, so clearly ng-click is just not working. Any ideas?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plunker for that? And what do you mean by "declared globally"?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you put your function in the controller and assign it to the $scope.

```
<a ng-click="action();">

function TracklistController($scope){
    $scope.action = function(){ ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ngClick` doesn't accept arbitrary JavaScript or functions defined outside of Angular! `ngClick` accepts an [AngularJS expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). For example, `data-ng-click="foo()"` will call `foo` on the current scope!

Comment: And as a sidenote, you might want to look into `ngHref` for `href` attributes that contain expressions! Just a heads up.